# One-One and Onto Function between Sets

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $A=\{x^2\mid 0<x<1 \}$ and let $B=\{x^3\mid 1<x<2 \}$. Now my question

> is there a *one-one* and *onto* function from $A$ to $B$? or
>
> is there a function which is *one-one* but not *onto*? or
>
> is there a function which is *onto* but not *one-one*? or
>
> there is no function which is *one-one* and *onto*?"

Arguments:

The sets $A$ and $B$ are infinite and also uncountable...so i think there is a function which is $one-one$ and $onto$ but i cannot find one...

Comment: If I read your notation correctly, both sets are intervals, open on both their ends. So the answer is *YES, there is at least one such function* which satisfies at least one of four conditions given.

Comment: If I understand your notation then $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,8)$. Is that correct? If so then why this peculiar notation?

Comment: Nice thing about reals, is they are a continuum.  A = (0,1) and B = (1,8).  f (a) = 7x +1 is 1-1 and onto.  Doesn't matter how they were defined or "squeezed" into the interval.  As they contain *all* points in the continuum any map, even those that seem the wrong "speed" that contain all points contain all points.  Using the definitions directly f (a) = $(\sqrt {a} +1)^3$ is also 1-1 and onto but we struggle?

Comment: There also exists functions $A\to B$ which are one-to-one but not onto and functions that are onto but not one-to-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:A \to B$ with $f(a) = 7a+1$ is 1-1 & onto.

$f:A \to B$ with $f(a) = a+1$ is 1-1 & not onto.

$f:A \to B$ with $f(a) = |(a-0.5)|.14 + 1$ is not 1-1 & onto.

Comment: ...and $f:A \to B$ with $f(a) = 3$ is not 1-1 & not onto.

Comment: @CiaPan Sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The map
$$f(x) = (\sqrt{x} + 1)^3$$
goes from $A$ to $B$. Can you find an inverse?

Comment: Easier to just take f (x) = 7x +1.

Answer (score 2):

As fleabood points out:

$f:(0,1)\to(1,8)$ prescribed by $x\mapsto1+7x$ is a bijection.

As Henrik suggests: there are also functions $(0,1)\to(1,8)$ that are one-to-one and not onto or that are not one-to-one and onto.